# RestKit API mappings

Tags: ios, xcode4.5, restkit

```
response =     {
    result =         {
        Accounts =             {
            row =                 (
                                    {
                    FL =                         (
                                                    {
                            content = 892498000000115001;
                            val = ACCOUNTID;
                        },
                                                    {
                            content = 892498000000063001;
                            val = SMOWNERID;
                        },
                                                    {
                            content = harsha;
                            val = "Account Owner";
                        },
                                                    {
                            content = Basheer;
                            val = "Account Name";
                        },
                                                    {
                            content = "(null)";
                            val = Phone;
                        },
                                                    {
                            content = "(null)";
                            val = Fax;
                        },
                                                    {
                            content = "2013-07-30 03:46:16";
                            val = "Created Time";
                        },
                                                    {
                            content = "2013-07-30 03:46:16";
                            val = "Modified Time";
                        },
                                                    {
                            content = "2013-07-30 03:46:16";
                            val = "Last Activity Time";
                        },
                                                    {
                            content = "(null)";
                            val = Address;
                        },
                                                    {
                            content = "(null)";
                            val = Mobile;
                        },
                                                    {
                            content = "(null)";
                            val = Landline;
                        },
                                                    {
                            content = "(null)";
                            val = EmailId;
                        }
                    );
                    no = 1;
                },        {
    FL =         (
                    {
            content = 892498000000114001;
            val = ACCOUNTID;
        },
                    {
            content = 892498000000063001;
            val = SMOWNERID;
        },
                    {
            content = harsha;
            val = "Account Owner";
        },
                    {
            content = 333333333;
            val = "Account Name";
        },
                    {
            content = "(null)";
            val = Phone;
        },
                    {
            content = "(null)";
            val = Fax;
        },
                    {
            content = "2013-07-27 01:13:54";
            val = "Created Time";
        },
                    {
            content = "2013-07-27 01:13:54";
            val = "Modified Time";
        },
                    {
            content = "2013-07-27 01:13:54";
            val = "Last Activity Time";
        },
                    {
            content = "(null)";
            val = Address;
        },
                    {
            content = "(null)";
            val = Mobile;
        },
                    {
            content = "(null)";
            val = Landline;
        },
                    {
            content = "(null)";
            val = EmailId;
        }
    );
    no = 2;
}
            );
        };
    };
    uri = "/crm/private/json/Accounts/getMyRecords";
};
```

,   This is my Json response. I have a model object with four properties (subject, Eventowner, ownerid, activityid)

Need help in creating Entity mapping using RKManagedObjectStore in RestKit API

Thanks in advance

Comment: That isn't valid JSON, please correct it with the actual text. And what mappings have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks wain for ur immediate response. I have updated the comlete json response.

Comment: That really isn't nice JSON, do you have an option to change it?

Comment: There is no way to change this...

Comment: This will be very hard with RestKit then as you have nested arrays and keys in values. I think you will be better to read the JSON in and process it yourself rather than trying to get RestKit to do it.